# What is the better technique to create thick arrow signs that will be filled with text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an Angular app that precises different content like arrows (up, down, left, right) that are filled with text (info coming from the server), what would be the best strategy to represent those arrows?

SVG, Canvas, just an image or maybe use a JavaScript library for specific visualizations?

Note: The text inside the elements and the color of the elements may change based on the fetched data.

Note2: Because I am using Bootstrap, so far I have been using it like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/gugol/yhq3npxs/23/

```
<div class="">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left icon--size"></i>
    <span class="text--custom">5</span>
</div>
```

[image: Arrow with text in it]

Comment: can also be done with html/css. Lots of ways to do this...up to you to decide what fits best

Comment: @charlietfl by html and css you mean an image and place the text inside it with css?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Angularjs.  You are asking about a display technique, that angular doesn't help with nor interfere with.  You have shown an example that seems to do what you want, that doesn't have angular;  this same example would work if angular were included on the page.

Comment: @Claies Well, it may or may not have some meaning. It could help in the case of a js library (with an angular plugin already developed). If it does not give any relevant info to you is ok, but do not question my question please.